# How can I remove part of the URL in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am creating some htaccess rules as part of a wordpress site migration.

On the old website the URL was:

```
/product-category/spearfishing-fins/
```

On the new website, it is just **/spearfishing-fins/**

So I am just trying to remove 'product-category' which ought to be simple enough.

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^/product-category/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

and alternatively 

RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

and alternatively

```
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

None of these work - you can still access both :

```
/product-category/spearfishing-fins/
```

and

```
/spearfishing-fins/
```

Can you see anything that I'm missing?

Comment: What about `RewriteRule product-category/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Gave it a try just now, still loading both unfortunately